# How does this circuit cause the lights to blink and after another?

Tags: transistors, led, circuit-design

I was toying around with electronic component and came to an interesting circuit. That's how it looks on my breadboard:
[image]

---

And this is a snippet from a simulation of an equivalent circuit:
[image]

As I understand, it's all about supplying the base of the transistor with a sufficient voltage and at the same time, reducing the base voltage at the other transistor. I'm not sure how the resistors and the capacitors together are doing that coordinated work.

What is the trick here that achieves this behavior?

More generally, I'm interested in using resistors/capacitors/transistors to create various blinking patterns with LEDs, and I feel that this circuit has the core idea to be able to do so.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: A quick google search will give you hundreds of explanations of this circuit, for example - http://www.davidbridgen.com/astable.htm

Comment: @HandyHowie only if I know what to search for, "Transistor astable multivibrator". I did a ton of search. Thank you for the link, I'm checking this!

Comment: @Toi Yiot, If you want to deeply understand the circuit operation and what the idea behind this famous circuit is, I recommend the Operation section of the [Wikipedia page](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivibrator#Operation) (it was mainly written by me in 2011, so I can answer any questions you may have).

Comment: You can get better responses from "CMOS Schmitt Inverter Astable Osc". with only 1 RC part.   Many people use Transistor Astable with 9V battery and ignorant of exceeding Veb=5V  on rapid discharge  This cct was designed before CMOS was invented